# What is the variance of Y = AX where A is a matrix?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, covariance

Here $X,Y$ are vector of length $n$ and $A$ is  a $n\times n$ matrix. Suppose the covariance matrix $D(X)$ is known?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This (linear transform) is typically listed as a property of covariance, but easy to show as well:
$$\begin{align}\operatorname{cov}(AX)&=\mathbb E[AXX^TA^T]-\mathbb E[AX]\mathbb E[X^TA^T]\\&=A\mathbb E[XX^T]A^T-A\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[X^T]A^T\\&=A(\mathbb E[XX^T]-\mathbb E[X]\mathbb E[X^T])A^T\\&=ADA^T\end{align}$$

Comment: I think in the general case, for complex-valued variables, those super-T should be super-H